# TomEE JPA MySql Configuration "An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted"

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I'm new to Java EE, spending some times in learning it.
Several hours on this error, cannot find exact similar questions, exept one student on udemy Q&A in same udemy course, but teacher cannot help the student.

The tutorial is teaching persistence using TomEE and JPA on MySQL.

**I'm using Eclipse:**
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

**TomEE Version:**
Tomcat v9.0 Server

**TomEE using JRE:**
jdk-12.0.1

**Project Java Build Path --> Module Path --> Execution Environment:**
JavaSE-10 (jdk-12.0.1)

**Java Compiler:**
Use compliance from execution environment JavaSE-10

**Actual MySql Connector in lib TomEE folder (tried several):**
mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar

This is my tomee.xml

```
<tomee>
    <Resource id="connessioneCorsoWeb" type="DataSource">
        JdbcDriver          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl             jdbc:Mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/corso_java_web?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC
        UserName            root
        Password            admin
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

this is the persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="corsoWebPersistence">
        <jta-data-source>connessioneCorsoWeb</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openejb.jpa.auto-scan" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The console message on starting application does not help me

> INFO: Undeploying app: D:\Shared\Studio\Java EE Developer - La guida
>   completa\apache-tomee-8.0.0-M3-plume\apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0-M3\webapps\corso-web
>   Aug 16, 2019 12:11:31 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
>   invoke SEVERE: Error destroying child
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle
>   transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   in state [STARTING_PREP]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:814)
>     ...

What can I look at to go deeper?

EDIT:

Removing persistence.xml the server starts.

Adding persistence.xml with only lines:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
</persistence>
```

the server starts.

Just right modifying persistence.xml as this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

the server fails.

This is a more exhaustive extract from the current console:

> ... Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal SEVERE:
>   Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war
>   StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.resolve(LinkResolver.java:55) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:37) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:33) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.resolvePersistenceRefs(AutoConfig.java:223)
>   at org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy(AutoConfig.java:197) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
>   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1033)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1286)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
>
> Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
>   invoke SEVERE: Error destroying child
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle
>   transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   in state [STARTING_PREP] at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:316)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:814)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1656)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1636)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1317)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
>
> Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
>   invoke SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   ... 21 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1320)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.resolve(LinkResolver.java:55) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:37) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:33) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.resolvePersistenceRefs(AutoConfig.java:223)
>   at org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy(AutoConfig.java:197) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
>   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1033)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1286)
>   ... 32 more
>
> Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
>   invoke SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   ... 13 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   ... 21 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   ... 21 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1320)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.resolve(LinkResolver.java:55) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:37) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:33) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.resolvePersistenceRefs(AutoConfig.java:223)
>   at org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy(AutoConfig.java:197) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
>   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1033)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1286)
>   ... 32 more
>
> Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
>   invoke SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat
>   is unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475) Caused
>   by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   ... 13 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>   ... 21 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso-web]]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>   at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>   ... 21 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1320)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5048)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.resolve(LinkResolver.java:55) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:37) at
>   org.apache.openejb.util.LinkResolver.add(LinkResolver.java:33) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.resolvePersistenceRefs(AutoConfig.java:223)
>   at org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy(AutoConfig.java:197) at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
>   at
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1033)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1286)
>   ... 32 more
>
> Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke INFO: Pausing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke INFO: Pausing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke INFO:
>   Stopping service [Catalina] Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager stop INFO: Stopping
>   server services Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
>   INFO: Undeploying app: D:\Shared\Studio\Java EE Developer - La guida
>   completa\apache-tomee-8.0.0-M3-plume\apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0-M3\webapps\ROOT
>   Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler
>   doResourceDestruction INFO: Closing DataSource: connessioneCorsoWeb
>   Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke INFO:
>   Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Aug 18, 2019 3:21:18 PM
>   jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke INFO:
>   Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

**Any single idea would be very appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved, to be very clear:
in Udemy course was used
Tomcat v8.0 Server (apache-tomee-7.0.4)
instead I was using
Tomcat v9.0 Server (apache-tomee-8.0.0-M3-plume)

Now with old version is not necessary, but with tomee-8.0.0 it is necessary to set JPA in Project Facets (when checking JPA screen alert to configure it), or in JPA project properties.

I've tested both tomee versions, now both working.

This is a screen of my JPA config in my Tomcat v9.0 Server (apache-tomee-8.0.0-M3-plume)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="corsoWebPersistence">
        <jta-data-source>connessioneCorsoWeb</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="openejb.jpa.auto-scan"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: thanx for your help. for now I downgraded to Tomee 7.0.4 and Java8 as in the udemy course. Now the web application runs. Now I noticed in Project Facets a check for JPA... maybe latest version of Tomee need such configuration...? In weekend I investigate more... (sorry if my doubts are silly, but i'm beginner in java and even less in JavaEE)

Comment: You're fine, don't be afraid to ask intelligent questions. :) I'm glad I was able to help. Please vote my answer up and click the green accept checkbox if you found it useful